# testing PUT update is not working on RSPEC ( Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

So I'm testing one of my controller in RSPEC and I'm trying to test the whole update shenanigans. This is what i have in the RSPEC

```
 describe 'PUT update' do
         before :each do
           @user = Factory(:user,name: "Lawrence Smith")
         end

      context "valid attributes" do
        it "located the requested @user" do
          put :update, :id => @user, user: Factory.attributes_for(:user)
          assigns(:user).should eq(@user)      
        end

        it "changes @user's attributes" do
          put :update, :id=> @user.id, user: Factory.attributes_for(:user, name: "Larry Smith")
          @user.reload
          @user.name.should eq("Larry Smith")

        end

      end
```

And this is what i have in the controller

```
def update
#update and save
@user = User.find(params[:id])
respond_to do |format|
if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  sign_in @user
  format.json{render :json => @user ,:status => :created, :location => @user }
else
  format.json { render :json => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
end
end
```

end
So apparently the the @user.reload doesn't really refresh the ActiveRecord, as my errors showed that the name has not been changed at all. Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you can pass object in get or post parameters. Anyways try like this
describe 'PUT update' do
         before :each do
           @user = Factory(:user,name: "Lawrence Smith")
         end

```
  context "valid attributes" do
    it "located the requested @user" do
      put :update, :id => @user, user: Factory.attributes_for(:user)
      assigns(:user).should eq(@user)      
    end

    it "changes @user's attributes" do
      put :update, :id=> @user.id, :user_name => Factory.attributes_for(:user, name: "Larry Smith").name
      @user.reload
      @user.name.should eq("Larry Smith")

    end

  end
```

and this in controller

```
def update
#update and save
@user = User.find(params[:id])
respond_to do |format|
if @user.update_attributes(:name => params[:user_name])
  sign_in @user
  format.json{render :json => @user ,:status => :created, :location => @user }
else
  format.json { render :json => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
end
end
```

I think you are getting what I explained here.

Thanks

Comment: But wouldn't that only allow the user to only update the name attribute?

Comment: @DaigoUmehara ofcourse, only name can be updated in this case.

Comment: i tried your way, and they said it didn't recognize the method or variable name in the controller.  Besides, I dont want any aspect of the controller to be changed at all, I do want the user to be able to modify all the other attributes too. Thanks anyway